# WPF Copy button issue

Tags: wpf, copy-paste, commandbinding

I have copy paste button in my application. Initially both button has to be disabled, If I select any text from any textbox, then only copy button needs to be enabled. And once I copied something, Paste button needs to be enabled. I use this code in App.xaml.cs file:

My question is, how would I know that when do i have to enable this button, How to find out in CanCmdCopy function, if I selected any text or not ?

```
    #region CopyCommand
    private void CmdCopy(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        // code///
    }
    private void CanCmdCopy(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        args.CanExecute = ?????
    }
    #endregion
```

Thanks

Dee

Answer (score 3):

You should be using the default [ApplicationCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.aspx), they will have the behavior you are looking for. If you use a `ToolBar` it will work without doing anything else, otherwise you will have to use the [FocusManager.IsFocusScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.isfocusscope.aspx) property or Bind the `CommandTarget` directly. Beware that if there is anything in the Clipboard the Paste Button will be enabled. You can use the `ClipBoard.Clear` Method to reset the Clipboard.

i.e:

**Example 1**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <StackPanel >
    <ToolBar>
        <Button  Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy">Copy</Button>
        <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste">Paste</Button>
    </ToolBar>
    <TextBox BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    <TextBox BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" />

  </StackPanel >

</Window>
```

**Example 2**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <StackPanel >
      <TextBox BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
      <TextBox BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
      <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True" >
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Button Grid.Column="0" Height="50" Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" >Copy</Button>
          <Button Grid.Column="1" Height="50" Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste">Paste</Button>
      </Grid >
  </StackPanel >
</Window>
```